# Tag popup is showed under the pending edit window

Tags: bug, tags, design, suggested-edits, popups

When post contains a pending edit the link below the post's body says `edit(1)`. Pressing this link leads to displaying the edit review popup window.

Hovering the mouse pointer over the question's tags leads to popuping tag info under the pending edit window, i.e. there is some Z-order issue:

> [image: tag popup Z-order is wrong]